# Does Active Directory uses LDAP natively?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I was asked to use LDAP over SSL (LDAPS) in our domain. Does it require any change in AD itself? Does AD use LDAP natively? Or is it something need to be done in application level that approach AD using LDAP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LDAP to talk to AD. The difference would be the port it uses.

Regular LDAP port 389 (unecrypted) and LDAPS over SSL uses port 636.

What needs to be changed for you is difficult to answer without knowing anything about your environment.

Comment: Thanks. So does it mean AD does use LDAP by default?

Comment: @user2156586Yes.

Comment: The LDAP protocol is the Active Directory core protocol, which means that LDAP is the only wire protocol that is supported by Active Directory.

(Active Directory makes use of Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) versions 2 and 3, Microsoft's version of Kerberos, and DNS as well)


read here : 

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961766.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396